# Metasearch how to disable required fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ho do I disable required fields in a Metasearch form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used simple_form_for all the fields got required fileds,
but with form_for no fileds are required